# Jasmine unit test file dependency load order (chutzpah)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

we're using chutzpah with VS2015 to test jasmine javascript tests which is working just great with VS2015 context menu and as a console app.

However I've run into some issues where by if example1.js uses example2.js but chutzpah loads example2.js first it will fail as it can't find this dependency.

In the chutzpah.json file we can name the files so that they load in the order we want but this is annoying as we will have to do this and ensure the order is correct each time a new file is loaded.

so the problematic way is this:

```
{
  "Path": "../www/js",
  "Includes": [ "*.js" ]
}
```

and to get it working ive had to use the above but additionally add:

```
{ "Path": "../www/example2.js" },
{ "Path": "../www/example1.js" }
```

Its going to get a bit annoying soon if we need to do this each time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to explicitly list the order like you did in the second block or switch to using an AMD loader like Require.JS which lets you codify dependencies as part of your JS files.